# Oracle SQL: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN"

Tags: oracle, plsql

Why is it that I get this error when executing this code?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE evenorodd(X IN NUMBER) IS
BEGIN

IF MOD(X,2) = 0 THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('even');
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('odd');
END IF;
END;
BEGIN
evenorodd(15);
END;
/
```

Comment: just a separate block for calling the function, i asssssssume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `/` at the end of the procedure to terminate the statement and before the PL/SQL anonymous block:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE evenorodd(X IN NUMBER) IS
BEGIN

IF MOD(X,2) = 0 THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('even');
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('odd');
END IF;
END;
/

BEGIN
evenorodd(15);
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1f65a46f1bf456baed4a18c7d107e829)*